Correct intuition about hypergeometric RV and sampling without replacement
Given $N, ~K \leq N$ and $n \leq N$, random variable $X\sim H(n,K,N)$ if $X$ counts the number of special items in a random sample of size $n$, obtained without replacement from population $N$ which has $K$ special items.
Now, we can write:
$$X = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$$
Where $X_i$ is 1 or 0 depending on whether the $i$th item picked in the sample is a special item or not.
I am confused about the following. Depending on whether $X_1 = 1$ or not, the distribution of $X_2$ would change. Yet, it seems clear that $E(X_i) = K/N$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = (K/N) ( 1 - K/N )$ for all $i$s.
How can one reconcile the fact that each of the $X_i$'s has a different distribution and are possibly dependent on each other yet they all have the same first and second moments and quite possibly higher moments as well?

X-posted to /r/learnmath

Two pointers:
$\bullet$ Expectation is a linear functional.
That is, if $X=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb I_i, $ then $\mathbf EX=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf E\mathbb I_i.$
$\bullet$ Since $\mathbb I_i$s are dependent, compute $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Cov}}(\mathbb I_i, \mathbb I_j) $ and use it to compute $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Var}}(X) $ by using the formula $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Var}}(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb I_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Var}}(\mathbb I_i)+{\sum\sum}_{i\ne j}\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Cov}}(\mathbb I_i, \mathbb I_j). $

Sure. Thank you. Is it right to say that in this case, the $X_i$'s are NOT iid yet they have the same first and second moment?

That is affirmative.

Wow, the hypergeometric is one of the most difficult RV's I have come across then. Just curious to know if the third or any higher moments of the $X_i$'s differ?

There is nothing peculiar about it. You can check SRSWR and how moments are calculated in this scheme.

Actually, my puzzlement / amazement is over whether / how two RVs, $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be dependent/nonidentically distributed and yet have the same first two/possibly higher moments. You are right that this is a general question and not something specific about hypergeometric RV. Sorry to bother you in an extended fashion -- is it true in general that if all of the moments of two RVs are the same then they are identically distributed?

Read about Hamburger moment problem. That would provide you an answer.

You can also check example $2.3.10$ of Casella and Berger to see moments don't determine a distribution uniquely.

Counterexample to question in comments:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical
