# Laplace transform and density

Tags: random-variable, density-function, moment-generating-function

It is true that the Laplace transform of a (positive) random variable characterises that random variable, just like its density?

($L_X(z) = E(exp(-Xz))$)

Answer (score 2):

Up to a change of sign in the exponent, the Laplace transform is the moment generating function.

The MGF only characterizes a random variable *if the MGF converges* in an open interval around 0.

This isn't automatically the case, even when all moments exist (e.g. see the lognormal).

By contrast the characteristic function (which up to sign in the exponent is the same as the Fourier transform) *does* characterize a random variable.

For more information, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/proving-that-mgf-determines-pdf-when-the-pdf-is-defined-for-whole-real-line), and the several threads linked to from there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Laplace transform characterises the random variable if it converges in an open interval around 0. Is it correct. Could you expand a little bit on that condition. What does it mean?

Comment: Yes, for the same reason that the MGF does. To be specific, the claim applies to the two sided Laplace transform. Details are [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46068/805). Were you after a definition of 'converges' or 'open interval'?

Comment: The result is basically dealt with [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/a-proof-involving-properties-of-moment-generating-functions)

Comment: "If $L_X(\cdot) = L_Y(\cdot)$, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution." This statement is wrong in general, right?

Comment: The thing is, if the integrals for $E(e^{-Xz})$ converge (so that it's meaningful to compare them for equality) then the equality of the two in an open interval around 0 would imply they *do* have the same distribution.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So, in fact, it suffices to have the equality in an open interval around 0 rather than on the whole positive half line.