# Bound for weighted sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, approximation, saddlepoint-approximation

Suppose I have some independent Poisson-distributed random variables $X_1 \ldots X_N$ with parameters $\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_N$. These can be thought of as processes where each arrival/event generates a loss of $a_1 \ldots a_N$. What I'm ultimately looking for is an upper bound $X^*$ for the loss per unit time (hour) to some confidence level $\alpha$, i.e. an $X^*$ such that

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_iX_i \leq X^*\right) \geq 1-\alpha$$

I am mainly interested in (efficient to calculate) approximations, since I don't expect an explicit solution to exist.
As far as I understand an explicit calculation of the probability alone would involve $N$-fold nested sums (of which one can be turned into a Gamma function). My parameters are $N \in \{5 \ldots 10\}$, $\lambda_i \in [1 , 20]$, so this generates awfully many terms.

Is there a better way than Monte-Carlo simulation?
Is approximation of $X_i$ as Gaussian distributed and the following calculations for the standard deviation of the (weighted) sum sensible? Maybe with corrections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the saddlepoint approximation. I will follow closely my answer to [Generic sum of Gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions/137318#137318) .  For the saddlepoint approximation I will follow Ronald W Butler: "Saddlepoint approximations with applications" (Cambridge UP).  See also the post  [How does saddlepoint approximation work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work)

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$.  Let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be positive real numbers. We define the random variable $X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$ and want an approximation for the distribution of $X$. When the weights $a_i$ are integers and $n$ is not to large, we can use numerical convolution. For the general case the saddlepoint approximation gives a good approximation for the density (probability) function.

The cumulant generating function for $X_i$ is given by $K_i(s) = \lambda_i (e^s - 1)$, $s \in (-\infty, +\infty)$.  The cumulant generating function of $X$ is then
$$
   K(s) = \sum_{i=1}^n K_i(a_i s) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (e^{a_i s} - 1)
$$
We will need the first two derivatives, given by
$$
  K'(s) = \sum \lambda_i a_i e^{a_i s}   \\
  K''(s) = \sum \lambda_i a_i^2 e^{a_i s} 
$$
The saddlepoint equation is given by
$$
   K'(\hat{s})=x
$$
which defines $\hat{s}=\hat{s}_x$ implicitly as a function of $x$.

The saddlepoint density function (for $x>0$) is now given by
$$
   \hat{f}(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi K''(\hat{s})}} \exp\left(K \hat{s} - \hat{s} x\right)
$$
and the probability that $X=0$ is given (exactly) by
$$
  \hat{f}(0) = \exp(-\sum \lambda_i)
$$
An implementation in R is below:

```r
# Saddlepoint approximation for a weighted sum of independent 
#  Poisson Random variables:

# Needs R 3.1.0 or newer (for extra argument of uniroot)
make_cumgenfun  <-  function(lambda, a) {
    # we return list(lambda, a, K, K',  K'')
    n  <- length(lambda)
    m  <- length(a)
    stopifnot( n==m, lambda>0,  a>0)
    return( list(lambda=lambda, a=a,
            Vectorize(function(s) {sum(lambda * (exp(a*s)-1))} ),
            Vectorize(function(s) {sum(lambda * a * exp(a*s))} ),
            Vectorize(function(s) {sum(lambda * a* a *exp(a*s))} 
    )))
}
# Probability that X=0:

P0  <- exp(-sum(lambda))

# Functions to get expectation and variance of X:  

Ef  <-  function(lambda, a) sum(lambda*a)
Vf  <-  function(lambda, a) sum(lambda*a*a)

solve_speq  <-  function(x, cumgenfun) {
    # Returns saddlepoint!
    lambda  <-  cumgenfun[[1]]
    a       <-  cumgenfun[[2]]
    Kd      <-  cumgenfun[[4]]
    uniroot(function(s) Kd(s)-x, lower=-100,  upper=+100,
            extendInt="yes")$root
}

# For an example,  define
set.seed(1234)
lambda <- 1:10
a      <- runif(10, 0.5, 3)
E  <- Ef(lambda, a)
V  <- Vf(lambda, a)


# Now,  a function giving the (uncorrected ) saddlepoint density. 
# We include the special case for x=0  

    make_fhat  <-  function(lambda, a) {
        cgf1  <-  make_cumgenfun(lambda, a)
        K  <- cgf1[[3]]
        Kd <- cgf1[[4]]
        Kdd <- cgf1[[5]]
        # function finding fhat for one specific x:
        fhat0  <- function(x) if (x==0) P0 else {
            # solve saddlepoint equation:
            s  <-  solve_speq(x, cgf1)
            # calculating saddlepointdensity value:
            (1/sqrt(2*pi*Kdd(s)))*exp(K(s)-s*x)}
        #Returning a vectorized version:
        return(Vectorize(fhat0))
    } # end make_fhat
```

and running this code in R:

```r
> fhat  <-  make_fhat(lambda, a)  
> E
[1] 94.72556
> V
[1] 185.3017
> sqrt(V)
[1] 13.61256
> fhat(0)
[1] 1.299581e-24
> fhat(94)
[1] 0.02938575
> fhat(107)
[1] 0.01861648
> integrate(fhat, lower=0, upper=Inf)
1.001878 with absolute error < 3.6e-05
>
```

The last integration can be used to correct `fhat` to get integral 1 (not shown here).

Finally, we can get a plot of the approximate density:

```r
> plot(fhat,  from=60,  to=130)
```

[image: Approximate density by saddlepoint approximation]

Now, you can yourself compare this with a normal approximation and with simulations. It should be quite accurate!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code, it seems to work.
However I hadn't heard about saddlepoint estimations before and therefore I don't fully understand how it works. You produce a generic distribution with the same cumulants?

Comment: The saddlepoint-approximation needs the moment generating function to exist. And yes, it builds on the cumulants---all of them, not only the first two as the central limit theorem does.  You should have a look at the referenced book by Butler!

Comment: What I meant to say is that it would take me more time (some days - weeks) to read up on this than I can spare right now. Thanks for the reference anyway! Btw in my case a Gaussian approximation is quite close to the saddlepoint estimation (are the higher cumulants of a Poisson close to those of a Gaussian?)

Comment: Nice. Perhaps that "How does the saddlepoint approximation work?" question is worth having on site. $\qquad$ \[In the end I [did](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183313/bound-for-weighted-sum-of-poisson-random-variables#comment348601_183355) ask it.]