# What does the MGF do when its parameter is other than 0?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, moments, moment-generating-function

I've only seen the MGF used when it takes 0 as it parameter and then derived for the nth moment.

What does the MGF tell us when the parameter is other than 0?

Comment: For an idea of what it can be used for have a look at this posts:   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions/137318#137318              http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183313/bound-for-weighted-sum-of-poisson-random-variables/183355#183355